# How to keep a record of running applications on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have been using Raspbian OS in my Raspberry Pi.I want to keep a track of the applications that runs on my Pi.Some sort of script that runs in the background and records the name of the application that runs on my Pi and stores it in a file.How to get started with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will save the currently running processes to /tmp/process.log

```
top -b -n1 > /tmp/process.log
```

or use >> to append to the log.

Now, set up a cron job to run that at your desired interval. Can make a script, and point the crontab to it.

If hourly is enough, put the above in a shell script (.sh), and put that script into /etc/cron.hourly

Comment: Thanks It works.But the process.log contains a lot of junk information as well.I mean a huge list of processes.I want only the main processes(like Minecraft Pi,Epiphany browser).So is there any way to obtain the same? Also the process.log didn't list out scratch though it was running.Also I'm a rookie at using linux.

Comment: Look up "top" and "ps" - you can filter by user, etc.